Find the irradiance on an area element from a finite Lambertian source
This question came up after reading Robert Boyd's textbook "Radiometry and the detection of Optical Radiation".

Problem:
Determine the irradiance $E$ on an area element positioned a distance $r$ from the center of a spherical Lambertian source of uniform radiance $L$, as shown in the figure.


Actually, Boyd solves the problem in section 2.5 of the text by using the symmetry of the problem:
Multiply the surface area of the sphere by the radiant exitance of a Lambertian source ($\pi L$) to get the flux emitted by the source ($4\pi^2 R^2L$). This flux must be equal to the flux arriving to a Gaussian spherical surface of radius $r$ with area $4\pi r^2$. Thus the irradiance at distance $r$ is given by $$E=\frac{\pi R^2 L}{r^2}.\tag{1}\label{*}$$
My approach is to sum the contribution of infinitesimal surface elements on the sphere to the irradiance at $\mathrm{d}A^\prime$:
The solid angle subtended by $\mathrm{d}A^\prime$ at $\mathrm{d}A$ is
$$\mathrm{d}\Omega=\frac{\mathrm{d}A^\prime}{\rho^2}\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot\hat{\rho}=\frac{\mathrm{d}A^\prime}{\rho^2}\cos\alpha$$
where $\vec{\rho}$ is the vector connecting the two surface elements and $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ is a unit vector normal to $\mathrm{d}A$ ($\alpha$ is the green angle in the figure).
The flux radiated from the projected area of $\mathrm{d}A$ and radiance $L$ into this solid angle is
$$\mathrm{d}^2\Phi=L\ \mathrm{d}A_{\mathrm{projected}}\mathrm{d}\Omega=L\ \mathrm{d}A\cos\alpha\ \mathrm{d}\Omega$$
where $\mathrm{d}A_{\mathrm{projected}}=\mathrm{d}A\cos\alpha$ is the projection of the source element on the line of sight.
Thus the contribution of $\mathrm{d}A$ to the irradiance at $\mathrm{d}{A^\prime}$ is
$$\mathrm{d}E=\frac{\mathrm{d}\Phi}{\mathrm{d}A}=L\ \frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\rho^2}\cos^2\alpha$$
In terms of the coordinates of the problem,
$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}A & =R^{2}\sin\theta\ \mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\phi\\
\rho & =\sqrt{R^{2}+r^{2}-2Rr\cos\theta}\\
\cos\alpha & =\frac{r\cos\theta-R}{\sqrt{R^{2}+r^{2}-2Rr\cos\theta}}\\
\mathrm{d}\Omega & =\frac{R^{2}\sin\theta\ \mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}\phi}{\left(R^{2}+r^{2}-2Rr\cos\theta\right)^{3/2}}\left(r\cos\theta-R\right),
\end{align*}$$
and the integral is
$$E=L\int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\phi\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2}\frac{R^{2}\sin\theta\ \left(z\cos\theta-R\right)^{2}}{\left(R^{2}+r^{2}-2Rr\cos\theta\right)^{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta.$$
Evaluating this with Wolfram, I get a different result than in equation \eqref{*} from the text.
Any help with finding the fault in my reasoning would be very welcome.

Boyd shows in chapter 5 that the irradiance produced at an off–axis angle by a Lambertian source oriented parallel to the receiver (left figure) is
$$E=\frac{\mathrm{d}\Phi}{\mathrm{d}A_{0}}=\frac{L\ \mathrm{d}A}{r^{2}}\cos^{2}\eta.$$
Now, what this expression changes to when $\mathrm{d}A$ is tilted at some angle $\alpha$ as in the figure on the right?

The effective area of the source decreases to
$$\mathrm{d}A_\mathrm{proj}=\mathrm{d}A\cos\alpha$$
i.e. $\mathrm{d}A$ multiplied by the cosine of the angle between $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ and the line of sight.
In our problem, $\cos\alpha$ is correctly expressed as in the question, but
$$\cos\eta=\frac{r-R\cos\theta}{\sqrt{R^{2}+r^{2}-2Rr\cos\theta}}$$
(not the same as $\cos\alpha$ !).
We thus have
$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}E&=L\ \mathrm{d}A\cdot\frac{\left(r-R\cos\theta\right)^{2}\left(r\cos\theta-R\right)}{\left(R^{2}+r^{2}-2Rr\cos\theta\right)^{5/2}}
\\
& =L\ R^2\sin\theta\cdot\frac{\left(r-R\cos\theta\right)^{2}\left(r\cos\theta-R\right)}{\left(R^{2}+r^{2}-2Rr\cos\theta\right)^{5/2}}
\end{align*}$$

A note about limits of integration: Not all the half–sphere is radiating into the receiver; surface elements for which $\cos\theta$ is negative do not contribute to the irradiance. The upper limit of integration is $\theta=\cos^{-1}R/r$, the polar angle for which $\cos\theta=0$.

The integral is:
$$E=L\int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\phi\int_{\theta=0}^{\cos^{-1}R/r}\ R^2\sin\theta\cdot\frac{\left(r-R\cos\theta\right)^{2}\left(r\cos\theta-R\right)}{\left(R^{2}+r^{2}-2Rr\cos\theta\right)^{5/2}}\mathrm{d}\theta$$
Computing with Wolfram and expanding the result around $R=0$ (i.e. $r\gg R$) gives
$$E=2\pi L\left( \frac{R^{2}}{2r^{2}}+\mathcal{O}\left(R^4\right)\right)$$
in agreement with the equation from the text.
